# Is there a way to make an article app in Angular without creating hundreds of components?

Tags: angular

I want to create a website in Angular that will have a bunch of articles which are basically static pages following the same template. I know it's possible to do it by creating a component for each one, but I kind of feel there's a better way.

At first, I thought about creating a single component that loads the article from an HTML file and renders it inside a div tag. It would take the appropriate file based on the route params. Also, I would like it to have Angular proprieties like routerLink for creating links to other articles as well. But I've looked for such solution without success, and I don't even know if this is the way to go.

Does anyone know how to do such thing?

Comment: You want to copy/paste static HTML within an Angular component? and somehow, this static HTML requires properties as `routerLink` and others? From where are you getting this static HTML?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I want. And the HTML would be in the project folder (either in the assets folder or in the app folder itself).

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I could figure it out on my own. I basically monitored the click event on the loaded file and overrode the default navigation with the Angular router on local links. I'll show the code I used for testing this feature. It worked just fine.

The file to be loaded:

```
<p><a href="/about">Local link</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank">External link</a></p>
```

The service method for loading the file:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

loadHTML(filename: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(`/assets/${filename}.html`, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

Loading the file on app load:

```
content = '';

constructor(private loadFile: LoadFileService, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadFile.loadHTML('test').subscribe(file => {
        this.content = file;
    });
}
```

Rendering the loaded file and checking for click events:

```
<p [innerHTML]="content" (click)="processLink($event)"></p>
```

Processing the click event and using Angular router on local URLs:

```
processLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    const el = <HTMLElement>event.target;
    if (el.nodeName === 'A') {
        const url = el.getAttribute('href');
        if (!url?.startsWith('http')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.router.navigateByUrl(url || '');
        }
    }
}
```